# How to use IBM java jar files in apex or Visualforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, static-resources

I am trying to incorporate IBM JAR files in apex or Visualforce in order to make an API call?

Should I be storing the JAR file folder in static resources?

If yes, is there a way to utilize the java class files in apex?

Any suggestions are appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is not possible AFAIK

Answer (score 3):

You can't run Java in Apex Code. While they are similar languages, Apex Code is not Java, and cannot directly run Java. You will have to "port" the code over to native Apex Code or host the code on an alternative server like Heroku, and call out to that instead.